# linq to dataset contains or any

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to solve a problem, but no success by now.

I have a datatable with 3 fields: f1, f2, f3 (string, string, double).

I would like to write a linq query, which makes the following: it selects the rows, where any of the values of f1 doesn't match to f2 values. In other words, which are the f2 values, which doesn't occur in the f1 field values.

How should I combine the where, any, contains keywords?

Comment: As I wrote, I'm trying to make a LINQ query. My object/collection is the Datatable.AsEnumerable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using LINQ extension function [GroupJoin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297(v=vs.95).aspx)

```
Dim dt As DataTable 'Your datatable
Dim uusi As IEnumerable(Of DataRow) = dt.AsEnumerable() _
            .GroupJoin(Of DataRow, String, DataRow)(dt.AsEnumerable(),
                 Function(dr) dr.Field(Of String)("f1"),
                 Function(dr) dr.Field(Of String)("f2"),
                 Function(row, matched)
                     If matched.Count > 0 Then
                         Return Nothing
                     End If
                     Return row
                 End Function) _
            .Where(Function(row) row IsNot Nothing)
```

`GroupJoin` method will find matched rows by given values (lambdas in second and third parameter)
Then last parameter is lambda/method which created result collection,
there we check if collection of matched rows empty
And `Where` function remove null rows from the collection